# Is it possible to increase the TPS on a a paper server to make red stone computation faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-redstone

Can I increase a Minecraft servers TPS to make computational redstone faster.

Answer (score 1):

1st. Don't use paper (or spigot or bukkit), they only do surface hack fixes that only break stuff and do very little of actually optimizing the game.
Should instead use [Fabric](https://fabricmc.net/). Fabric by itself does not change any of the vanilla game mechanics (forge rewrites Minecraft adding in heaps of its own bugs and changing vanilla behaviour) but allows other mods to do so instead

Now to the optimizations!
[Lithium](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lithium): Optimizes a lot of areas in entities, block updates, block/entity collisions, world border checks, ram/GC usage and TNT. This is ~90% of the lag
[Phosphor](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/phosphor): Optimizes light updates. Helps with chunk loading, chunk generation and normal light updates
[Carpet](https://github.com/gnembon/fabric-carpet): Mostly adds redstone and creative mode based features (like creative no-clip), but has a few optimizations as well (like disabling spawn chunks and optimizing redstone updates)
[Sodium](https://github.com/jellysquid3/sodium-fabric): Client-side only. Is like Optifine but much faster (Still in development, not released to the general public yet)

Sadly fabric does not support plugins that paper has, like CoreProtect or Plot^2, but does [WorldEdit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit)
JellySquids Discord: https://jellysquid.me/discord